# Using Vue-CLI to render WordPress body

Tags: wordpress, vue.js

So I have a question, and please tell me if this is possible or not, but let's say that I use the vue-cli to build an application and then I hook the vue app to `id="test"`.

Could I hook it to the `<body>` tag such as `<body id="test">` and then still keep my WordPress .php files and have specific places call in the vue components?

We are looking to hook vue as the full front-end which is the body, but still keep our .php files and only call in `<vue-component>` in specific places that we need inside the .php files?

Is this even possible?

Comment: In short - yes, it is possible

Comment: Having the same problem. I'm trying to match `Vue` with `Wordpress` using `vue-cli`. Everything works fine, `webpack` bundles files, and bundled file is included to Wordpress theme using `wp_enqueue_script` function. But the only problem is when I call a `Vue single file component`, the mounted functions run but the `template` tag wouldn't be compiled. Its name (e.g. `<my-card></my-card>`) is written directly in browser inspect mode